# Apple OCR 2023 - list of supported languages

Tags: ocr, ios16

Does anyone know where to get the full list of languages supported by Apple OCR for iOS16/17? The best if it’s official Apple website/document.
I did some research and found only 3rd party publications with just short list.
During research I found this pages and I thought that it might be what I’m looking for: [link 1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_text_in_images), [link 2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest/3152644-supportedrecognitionlanguages)
But it wouldn’t be Apple if I find the answer that simple 
So I rely on you, please share your wisdom.